# Use HTML Table without headers

Tags: tabulator

I've a table, where the normal guidance for HTML tables arn't followed.

My best move will be, to just create a proper JSON-object, and using that.

But i'll like to ask, if there is any options for parsing an HTML table, "without headers", and define them in Tabulator, instead.

I know the case id odd, but i'll just like to hear :-)

*Example where no `thead` and `th` is in the HTML-source:*

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr height="16">
            <td colspan="16">
                Something
            </td>
            <td colspan="16">
                14
            </td>
            <td colspan="16">
                2020-01-28
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im afraid not.

When Tabulator is built on a table element, it parses the HTML to create a JavaScript object for each row of the table, using the column headers as property names.

Without headers it would have no reasonable way to map the column values onto an object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up running through all rows, and handled the data manually - and used that object :-)

Answer (score 1):

I solve problem like this

```
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr height="16" hidden>
                <td colspan="16">
                </td>
                <td colspan="16">
                </td>
                <td colspan="16">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr height="16">
                <td colspan="16">
                    Something
                </td>
                <td colspan="16">
                    14
                </td>
                <td colspan="16">
                    2020-01-28
                </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for commenting. This is a old case, but I wanted to use an HTML table as the source of Tabulator. Back when it was not supported with the formatting I had. So the question was focused on how to handle the case, without manipulating the HTML itself.